# Как реализовать вывод фото на странице

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Написал скрипт, с помощью которого осуществляется загрузка фотографии на сервер. 
При загрузке данные о фото записываются в таблицу *photo_gallery* . 
Структура таблицы: **id** - id фото, **name** - имя фото(cat.jpg) , **folder** - папка, в которой лежит фото.

Хочу сделать bb-код, который можно было бы вписать в текстовое поле, и чтоб на странице появлялось фото. 
Например [image]15[/image],где 15 - id фото.

Прошу подкинуть идеи реализации подобного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов: поместить вывод всей страницы в буфер, при помощи функции ob_start(), затем после формирования страницы извлечь содержимое буфера (ob_get_contents()). Далее при помощи регулярного выражения, извлечь идентификаторы фотографий из всех bbCode [image]

```
\[image\](\d+)\[/image\]
```

Сформировать массив идентификаторов, сделать его уникальным и запросить из таблицы photo_gallery данные по фотографиям при помощи запроса

```
SELECT * FROM photo_gallery WHERE id IN (4324,23432,4324,423432)
```

Где 4324,23432,4324,423432 - последовательность из массива, объединить массив можно при помощи функции implode(). Затем можно сформировать два массива одинаковой длины: с регулярных выражений с идентификаторами вместо (\d+) и готовыми  тэгами и заменить bbCode в переменной с содержимым страницы, после чего страницу можно отправлять пользователю.